# Would like some help with Logic Gates, Trying to use two inputs to create three outputs

Tags: digital-logic

I'm totally lost and I've got no idea what to search to help find this. Basically I have two inputs [A,B] Where A represents the number 1 and B represents the number 2. I'm trying to make it so when 1 is "on" It turns on a little LED, and when two is "on" it turns a seperate LED on. I've got that, but I want to add an AND gate to make it so when both are on it turns a new LED on and the other two turn off. I've tried using a XOR gate & and gate but it can't differentiate the two signals, [1,2] Hopefully I can finally understand this. I'm currently using Logism to make it easy to see and understand. Thanks.

Comment: Think of this as 3 separate problems, one for each of the LEDs. Write a truth table for each one, giving the output for each combination of inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIVE7e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: mine's prettier :P

Answer (score 2):

**A Simpler Way?**

Given you haven't specified what rail the LEDs are connected to, it is actually possible to implement the solution showed by both @WhatRoughBeast and @RobhercKV5ROB (both are the same circuit effectively), using *just* three 2-input NAND gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMukhK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically the LEDs are wired up to act as inverters - if the output is high, then the LED is off. This allows all the gates to be transformed into NAND gates.

---

**Fun facts:**

This is also the most optimal way to design it using 7400/4000 series ICs (just one!).

It can also become the most optimal at the transistor level - by stripping away unused parts of the NAND gates, it could me made using just 5 NMOS transistors!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this easily with 3 AND gates & 2 inverters. Here's a schematic example:

[image: schematic]

The 3 AND gates turn on the LEDs. The 2 inverters turn off both the 'single' LEDs if the center 'dual' LED is lit due to 1=2=on

Comment: You beat me by 3 seconds. And mine is clearer.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yeah, I'm on my cell...no access to CircuitLab (& I'd have beaten you by 2 minutes if I didn't have to reboot the stinkin' thing to get the img to upload).

Comment: You do not need two inverters. Both of them are doing the same thing so one could be pulled out.